# Ajax Polling compartilhado entre abas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Antes de mais nada preciso informar a situação atual.

Possuo um site, nele existe um ajax polling, que faz requisições a cada 5 segundos para obter notificações e afins.

Todo o site é suportado por dois servidores, sendo um para NGINX e outro para MySQL. Entretanto, devido principalmente ao "`loop de requisições`" o servidor chega facilmente a ter 500 à 1500 requisições por segundo. Número que para mim é extremamente alto. O número máximo de conexões com o MySQL abertas simultaneamente é de 50, o que pra mim foi um tanto impressionante, *embora o limite seja muito maior que isso*. *Vale lembrar que conteúdo estático (CSS, JS, IMG) estão em cache por CDN externo, portanto esse número de requisições NÃO incluem tais arquivos, já monitorei isso também!* O tempo médio de resposta é de 200ms até 800ms, sendo a média 700ms, segundo o New Relic.

O problema é na maior parte das vezes o problema está no usuário abrir várias abas, inclusive eu. Confirmei isso quando inclui nos logs o tempo de cada usuário.

Dessa forma, um mesmo usuário pode fazer ao invés de 1 requisição a cada 5 segundos, efetuar 5 ou 20 requisições a cada 5 segundos, simplesmente porque cada aba irá "duplicar" a quantidade de requisições.

Isso não só aumenta as requisições como também faz com que as abas fiquem dessincronizadas, pois cada aba tem o "seu tempo" para atualizar, uma pode ter atualizado enquanto a outra não.

Queria saber se há alguma forma de compartilhar a informação recebida de UM AJAX entre as abas abertas, de maneira que apenas uma requisição fosse capaz de atender todas as janelas abertas. Da mesma maneira que apenas uma janela seria responsável por atualizar todo o conteúdo, resultando em apenas uma requisição a cada 5 segundos, ao invés de cada aba efetuar requisições a cada 5 segundos.

**Solução pensada...**

Uma requisição salva de maneira "persistente" as mudanças, incluindo o tempo que foi realizado a última consulta (ou definido por algum prazo de validade). Quando outra aba for executar irá verificar antes se a última consultado foi realizado a mais 5 segundos atrás. Se não, iria pegar os dados que já foram definidos pelo ajax de outra aba, que foram salvas, que estão atualizadas.

Eu pensei em usar o `Cookie` para isso, porém não sei se o `cookie` é capaz de ser acessado em outra aba quando definido por outra, sem necessidade de atualizar a página, acredito que não. Além disso o Cookie ira adicionar mais um dado para enviar a cada requisição, alguns bytes desnecessários.

Neste EXATO momento estou vendo o [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/), talvez supra a necessidade, pois acredito que seja acessível por outra aba sem atualizar a página.

**Existe alguma forma mais eficiente para fazer esse "compartilhamento de ajax" entre abas?**

*Isso seria uma medida temporária.
Estou pensando em usar WebSockets para isso, usando Ably.io ou Pusher, entretanto não sei quão eficiente seria, uma vez que o PHP passaria a executar um Curl unicamente para enviar as notificações.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pausar requisições na aba inativa

Você pode simplesmente pausar as requisições AJAX ao perceber que a aba não está mais ativa.

Para isso você terá que usar [Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/) ([disponível na maioria](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility) dos navegadores atuais).

Aproveite a sua função que executa a cada 5 segundos, e verifique se a aba está visível, senão estiver, mude uma variável para impedir futuras requisições, porém, deixe a função continuar rodando para sempre verificar se a visibilidade da página mudou.

Exemplo funcionando aqui:

```js
var timer = 0;
var period = 5000;
var visible = true; 

function onLoad() {
  timer = setInterval(checkLog, period);
  if(document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", visibilityChanged);
}

function visibilityChanged() {
  visible = (document.hidden)? false : true;
     document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += '<p>Visibilidade mudou: '+document.hidden+'</p>';
}

function checkLog() { 
  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += '<p class="'+visible+'">'+new Date()+'</p>';
}

onLoad();
checkLog();
```

```css
p{color:#fff;font-family:arial;padding:3px;background-color:blue}
.true{background-color:green;}
.false{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<div id="log">

</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brunogc/75do1wde/2/

### Comunicação entre as abas

Em teoria, sua solução com `Cookie` deveria funcionar, embora usar `localStorage` nesse caso seria mais adequado (devido a seu tamanho maior). Em ambos os casos eles podem ser acessados independentemente de qual aba criou.

Porém, você teria que criar uma lógica complexa para controlar a aba que faz a requisição e ainda implementar a sincronização dos dados entre elas.

Comment: Não tinha cogitado a ideia de pausar a requisição quando não estivesse visível.