# Um sistema de notificações usando setInterval + AJAX é ruim?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Por serem vários requests ao php+myql, pouco intervalados (coisa de milissegundos), multiplicados por vários users online ao mesmo tempo, isso fica inviável, no sentido de recursos computacionais?

Esses XHR's todos iriam dar "gargalo" no server, ou é tranquilo?

Se sim, que outra alternativa eu tenho? Sockets? (não entendo disso)

Comment: Tudo depende da quantidade de acessos e quanto recurso tem disponível. Por experiencia própria não só "dar gargalo" como ele tende a dar. Inclusive [aqui falei sobre o meu problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150432/ajax-polling-compartilhado-entre-abas). Mas cada caso é um caso, a diferença é que com o SSE (Server-Sent Events) ou Websockets você mantem apenas uma conexão e somente "envia dados" quando você realmente tiver algo novo. Se não quiser usar SSE ou Websockets você tem o Ajax Long Polling, que reduz o número de requisições. Mas, usar o Ajax Polling não é em si um problema.

Comment: Por gentileza, se conseguir algum conteudo ou tutorial poste aqui tbm... Estou pesquisando sobre o assunto e com dificuldades de entender o q procurar ou onde procurar sobre o conteudo relacionado.

Answer (score 2):

Se o `setInterval` for muito curto (milisegundos) você começa a correr o risco de ter inconsistências. Os requests podem começar a chegar em ordens diferentes das que foram executados e isso pode acarretar num dado desatualizado sobrescrevendo um atualizado. Pooling de AJAX funciona melhor para intervalos maiores.

Além disso você vai ter que ter uma infra bem parruda para aguentar o volume de requests. Imagine que cada usuário vai fazer 5 requests por segundo se o intervalo for de 200ms por exemplo.

O ideal seria trabalhar com WebSockets mesmo. Você mantém uma única conexão aberta e só atualiza o client quando receber um evento notificando que uma mudança ocorreu.

Não trabalho com PHP mas aparentemente [existem libs](http://socketo.me/) que facilitam a adoção do WebSockets.

Comment: +1, porém somente os browsers mais recentes suportam websockets.

Comment: @Washingtondacosta na verdade se você ignorar o IE 9 para baixo o que em muitos casos já é bem aceitável você consegue um suporte bem legal.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: Basicamente se você limita por TLS 1.2, *que é recomendado pela PCI Security Standards*, automaticamente todos que acessarem o site será compatível com Websockets, exceto o Opera Mini. Acho que incompatibilidade não é tão grande, inclusive é mais compatível que o SSE.

Answer (score 0):

Depende muito do propósito da sua aplicação. Se as requisições serão feitas em pequenos intervalos de tempo (milissegundo), o mais indicado seria trabalhar com nodejs, pois esse mantem uma conexão direta com o servidor e permite que as alterações sejam feitas em tempo real. Pesquise sobre NodeJS e veja como implementar em seu projeto!